# getting error "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id" while crawling links of a table

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

trying to crawl links given in table-tr-td[2] but facing  below error --selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id.

i have tried using selenium webdriver, but not getting whats the issue with seesion error.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from selenium import webdriver

    url="https://www.zaubacorp.com/company-list"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)

    driver.close()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table',{'id':'table'})
    body = table.find('tbody')
    for links in body.find_all('a'):
        print(links['href'])
```

please help me get through this.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are the closing browser before taking page_source value so selenium unable to get the session.Try now.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url="https://www.zaubacorp.com/company-list"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
driver.close()
table = soup.find('table',{'id':'table'})
body = table.find('tbody')
for links in body.find_all('a'):
 print(links['href'])
```